# Getting Errno 13 Permission Denied error when running a python code

Tags: python, macos

I am using SerpentAI, and I have to run a python script and it gives me this error.

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Applications/OpenEmu.app'

Here the Python code

```
    from serpent.game import Game

    from .api.api import OpenEmuAPI

    from serpent.utilities import Singleton




    class SerpentOpenEmuGame(Game, metaclass=Singleton):

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            kwargs["platform"] = "executable"

            kwargs["window_name"] = "Open Emu"


            kwargs["executable_path"] = "/Applications/OpenEmu.app"



            super().__init__(**kwargs)

            self.api_class = OpenEmuAPI
            self.api_instance = None

        @property
        def screen_regions(self):
            regions = {
                "SAMPLE_REGION": (0, 0, 0, 0)
            }

            return regions

        @property
        def ocr_presets(self):
            presets = {
                "SAMPLE_PRESET": {
                    "extract": {
                        "gradient_size": 1,
                        "closing_size": 1
                    },
                    "perform": {
                        "scale": 10,
                        "order": 1,
                        "horizontal_closing": 1,
                        "vertical_closing": 1
                    }
                }
            }

            return presets
```

I am using MacOS

Is there a solution to this or is it just SerpentAI that is messing up?

Comment: Could be that either the python executable isn't running with your permissions or you don't own the .app. `ls -l /Applications/OpenEmu.app` will tell you what the associated permissions are. If you are the owner of the machine, you probably need at least `drwxr-xr-x` permissions on it. `chmod` can help you there

Comment: @C.Nivs I think that the python file doesn't have the permission to use apps, OpenEmu already has 'drwxr-xr-x' on it, but the code doesn't. It has 'rwsr-xr-x'. Which 'chmod' line do I use?

Comment: Who is the owner of OpenEmu.app (`ls -l OpenEmu.app`)? If you aren't the owner, that could also raise the issue, since the python process will inherit your user permissions. Also, per [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3773795) post, not all apps run via their `.app` files. OpenEmu could be one. I can't access it at the moment due to firewall, but I can see later

Comment: @C.Nivs when I type ls -l it gives me this drwxr-xr-x. I'm pretty sure this means that I am the owner. I could be wrong on that.